# Add customer attribute to Enterprise google App for saml 2.0 authentication

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, saml-2.0, google-authentication

We have **Enterprise Google App** in my organization, i want to use Google app as a **IDP** for my Application(**SP**). I configured **saml 2.0** in google for **saml authentication** to **SP**(My Application). Here i am expecting one more attribute from google while sending response to SP(EX : IsAccessToApp = true/false per each user level). I want this attribute because, based on this attribute i can restrict the user to authorize my application(SP).

Question

1. How to create custom attribute in our Enterprise Google App?
2. How to change customer attribute value of each user in our Enterprise Google APP?
3. How many custom attributes i can create in our Enterprise Google App?

Please help me.

Comment: Any update on this.